# Algorithms on converting hex to IEEE-754 single-precision floating point number

Tags: computer-arithmetic

I need help with finding algorithm converting hex to IEEE-754 single-precision floating point number (without coding). I couldn't find any on the internet :(

For example, given input string `0xB9CD542`, we need to return string `0x1.39aa84p-104` where last number is in hexadecimal exponential form (single precision floating point number) rounded to 0

Comment: What sort of hex? Can you provide an example input and output

Comment: What does "hex" mean? Does it mean you are looking at a bit pattern like `0x3f800000` and want to determine its numeric value, 1.0 in this case? If so, there are tools for that, e.g. [this randomly selected website](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). There are also numerous websites explaining the format, e.g. [this randomly selected one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ieee-standard-754-floating-point-numbers/)

Comment: @AlexK for example, given input string `B9CD54`, we need to return string `0x1.39aa84p-104` where last number is in hexadecimal exponential form (single precision floating point number) rounded to 0

Comment: @njuffa I checked these websites, but they didn't provide algorithms... first one uses built-in functions

Comment: @regina Converting `0xB9CD54` to `0x1.39aa84p-104` is not a math problem, so this looks like a programming question suitable for Stackoverflow. There should be no rounding (including truncation = round-toward-zero) involved when representing an IEEE-754 operand as a hex float. FWIW, as someone who does these kind of representation changes and conversions almost every day, I do not see how `0xB9CD54` maps to `0x1.39aa84p-104`. Did you mean `0xb9cd542`?

Comment: A single-precision floating-point number is generally eight hex digits in length. So your 6-digit example is not typical!

Comment: You might get different responses at the [Computational Science stack](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @njuffa I'm sorry, yes, I meant that :(

Comment: Does the [conversion example from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Converting_binary32_to_decimal) answer your question?

Comment: @regina Since the desired representation change is from raw hex to hexfloat, this boils down to a few logical operations for bit-field extraction, a few shifts, and the correct use of format specifiers: [worked example](https://godbolt.org/z/ozo14qcPf). I do not consider this a mathematical problem.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll bite:

If `0xB9CD54` (binary `00000000101110011100110101010100`) is an IEEE-754 single-precision number, then it can be decomposed as follows:

Sign bit = `0`, so number is positive
Biased exponent = `00000001`, so unbiased exponent is `-126`
Mantissa (including implied leading `1`) = `101110011100110101010100` = `0xB9CD54`

Shifting the mantissa left by 1 so that it starts with `1.` gives `1.739AA8`.

So we end up with `0x1.739AA8p-126`.

Conversely, the decimal form of `0x1.39aa84p-104` would seem to be `0xb9CD542` according to [this site](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html). So it looks like you need to check your sources!

Comment: Yes, it was `0xb9CE642`, I'm really sorry for inconvinience :(